# kubernetes minion not registering with api server on openstack, hostname being rejected

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, kubelet

I start the kubelet with

```
--cloud-provider=openstack and --cloud-config=openstack.conf and --hostname-override=192.168.1.136
```

and get this in the kubelet log:

> Unable to register node "pn-kube-minion_1-du27gtypmboj" with API
>   server: Node "pn-kube-minion_1-du27gtypmboj" is invalid:
>   metadata.name: Invalid value: "pn-kube-minion_1-du27gtypmboj": must
>   match the regex
>   a-z0-9?(.a-z0-9?)* (e.g.
>   'example.com')

looks like hostname-override is being ignored and it's pulling the hostname info from the vm instead (I believe this is to satisfy cinder volume mounting)

Is this a known issue? Any work-arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22984

> For nodeName, hostname-override will be ignored if you are using cloud provider, we will use the node name determined by your cloud provider to register the node with apiserver.

Comment: thanks Hang, this does confirm that the openstack cloud-provider ignores the hostname override, but it doesn't explain why node name being provided in the registration is being rejected.

Comment: Read again - `a-z0-9?(.a-z0-9?)*` does not include underscore `_`.